# App forces down when i m using put/getExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to pass data between two activities.In the first activity i m using this code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            switch(position){
         case 0: 


             Intent newActivity = new Intent(museum.this, museum_item.class);
           newActivity.putExtra("TXT_RESOURCE",R.string.infomuseum1);
            newActivity.putExtra("IMG_RESOURCE",R.drawable.infohistory);

            startActivity(newActivity);
             break;
```

and in the second i m using

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.museum); 


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String textResourceId = extras.getString("TXT_RESOURCE");
int imgResourceId = extras.getInt("IMG_RESOURCE");

TextView museum_item_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.museum_item_text);
museum_item_text.setText(textResourceId);


  ImageView museum_item_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.museum_item_image); 
  museum_item_image.setImageResource(imgResourceId);
```

but i m getting error and my app forces down..Where is my wrong?This is the logcat

```
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kostas.menu.heraklion/kostas.menu.heraklion.museum_item}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at kostas.menu.heraklion.museum_item.onCreate(museum_item.java:24)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
12-08 19:35:04.905: E/AndroidRuntime(7689):     ... 11 more
```

**museum_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/museum_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/museum_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you pointed out which line of your code (line 24, according to the logcat) is causing the problem. My guess is that you aren't finding one of the views `museum_item_text` or `museum_item_image`, the corresponding view variable is being set to null by the call to `findViewById`, and then you're getting a NPE on the next line.

Comment: line 24 is museum_item_text.setText(textResourceId);

Comment: @kgr - Then the problem is that there's no view with id `museum_item_text` in your museum.xml layout. If you have configuration-specific layout directories (res/layout-land, etc.) be sure to check every occurence of museum.xml for the problem.

Comment: i posted my .xml too...i m just using a simple layout folder

Comment: @kgr - You are using R.layout.museum when you call `setContentView`. If you should be using R.layout.museum_item, then that would explain why it can't find the `museum_item_text` view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line:

```
int textResourceId = extras.getInt("TXT_RESOURCE");
```

You are passing a string into the Intent's extras in the 1st Activity, but are trying to cast it as an int in the 2nd Activity.  The Intent's extras does not contain an int of "TXT_RESOURCE", which is why you're getting the NullPointerException.

**UPDATE**

The layout file you are using in setContentView() is R.layout.museum, however, you're TextView with id of museum_item_text is contained within the R.layout.museum_item file.

Comment: i changed it to String but the problem remains

Comment: and the logcat erros remains the same too

Comment: Please post your updated code, and point out which line is throwing the exception compared to the line number in your logcat

Comment: That wouldn't cause  NullPointerException

Comment: line 24 is museum_item_text.setText(textResourceId);

Comment: Can you confirm that the TextView with ID museum_item_text is contained within your layout?

Comment: @hooked82 no he doesnt attempt to do that. the third call is setContentView(), the 7th is findViewById(), should work...

Comment: @kgr  it looks like you're referencing the wrong layout file, see my updated "UPDATE" section in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ListView or something? Because if museum_item.xml is the layout of your list item, your call:

```
 TextView museum_item_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.museum_item_text);
```

will not find that view, because it is looking inside your main layout which is museum.xml